# Why is the SSRS Last() function not working consistently?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I'm newish to SSRS, so apologies if terminology isn't perfect.

Problem:
I have a table where a certain row grouping will have either one or two rows in it. When only one row exists, that row needs a bottom border. In the instance where the group has two rows, only the last row needs a bottom border.

I built a conditional border using the following function: =IIF(Last(Fields!SubgroupField.Value, "Parent Group") = Fields!SubgroupField.Value, "Black", "No Color"). This function should create a black bottom border for the cell when the field's value is equal to the last value of that field in the parent group.

This function works except in a few circumstances and I'm trying to understand why. The only clear commonality is that the failed cases have both cell values starting with the same letter, but not necessarily the same word. The sort is being performed correctly as the last cell's value is the last alphabetical value. *Apologies for the confusing wording, trying to convey the sorting is being done correctly and that there should be no reason such a simple function isn't working.*

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? If so, how did you fix it? I'm trying to better understand what is causing the actual issue. To me, this might be more of an SSRS error as the function should be fairly straightforward and the source data is seemingly correct.

If you don't know how to fix it, do you have an alternative to my conditional formatting problem? I can't think of a better way to conditionally format than by my current solution, but I'd love to hear other suggestions.

I built a conditional border using the following function: =IIF(Last(Fields!SubgroupField.Value, "Parent Group") = Fields!SubgroupField.Value, "Black", "No Color"). This function should create a black bottom border for the cell when the field's value is equal to the last value of that field in the parent group. I added a column that that simply ran the Last() function to show where the function thinks the last row in the group is and even this is not working correctly in the erroneous cases. In the failed cases, the first row is being identified as the last.

Comment: How about using a row number per group and checking if the row number is >1 as a  check condition instead?

Comment: That probably works, but I ended up solving it. I added an order by to the inbound query and that fixed it. Why? I'm not sure, but it did. Thanks for the response!